# Android L ViewAnimationUtils not found?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I've been testing the Android L SDK, and trying to get to know the new Material design and view animations.

Specifically I want to try to get the Reveal Effect working properly, but the class is missing.

http://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html#reveal

The specific line that fails me is

```
ValueAnimator anim =
ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
```

The ViewAnimationUtils class is missing - or am I missing some dependencies?

EDIT: For targetSDK, minSDK and compileSDK, I have these settings in my build.gradle file.

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 'L'
    targetSdkVersion 'L'
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... according to their rather broken JavaDocs, that should be in `android.view.ViewAnimationUtils`. Are you sure that your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) is set to API Level 20?

Comment: I'm using Android L, which is not exactly API 20. Let me try to import that directly. Could you link me to the JavaDocs? I'll update my question with the minSDK and targetSDK etc.

Comment: Doesn't exist in that namespace. It just doesn't seem to be there. Can't find any samples that use that particular function either.

Comment: @hnilsen Android L preview _is_ API 20. L final will be API 21.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's actually reporting v21. Download Developer Tools from Play and check it out. Nonetheless, it's L and 20 for all intents and purposes. And also not important for this question.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Android studio release. Android Studio reports the error, but the app still builds and runs for me.

Comment: I'll be damned. If I manually import it, and although the import is greyed out, it actually compiles and runs. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertKarl Please provide this as the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just compile against L and add the following.

```
import android.view.ViewAnimationUtils;
```

As I commented above this looks like a bug in the Android studio release. Android Studio reports the error, but the app still runs.

Comment: After more investigation it seems that Android Studio can't properly include the 'L' SDK, so we're working on 4.4.4 for syntax highlighting. This can be seen if you go into project details and check the project SDK. It says 4.4.4, API 19, when I try this.

Comment: Are you using 0.8.1? I see Compile Sdk Version - android-L

Comment: Yes, I'm on the newest version. More people have reported this, but I'm hopeful it will be fixed in a near release of AS. As long as I can compile and run, I'm happy, but it actually never occurred to me that I could try to run it when AS reported an error. It might be related to the fact that I upgraded an existing project, and didn't create a new project?

Comment: This post confirms it's an Android Studio bug, and it has been fixed. https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AlexRuiz/posts/28r2HyvcibF - explanation is: "the bug only happens if you have android-20 installed in your SDK Manager. There was one place in the code where matching was done by API level and Studio thought that 'android-L' and 'android-20' where the same."

Comment: If you like using ViewAnimationUtils, please star this issue so it can be backported into the Android Support Library.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87380